# How to find lines that begin with **

Tags: text-processing, grep, quoting

I need to find if any lines in a file begin with `**` .

I cannot figure out how to do it because `*` is interpreted as a wildcard by the shell.

```
grep -i "^2" test.out
```

works if the line begins with a 2 but

```
grep -i "^**" test.out
```

obviously doesn't work.

(I also need to know if this line ends with a `)` but have not attempted that yet).

Answer (score 19):

Use the `\` character to escape the * to make it a normal character.

```
grep '^\*\*' test.out
```

Also note the single quote `'` and not double quote `"` to prevent the shell expanding things

Comment: The first `*` doesn't need escaping in this particular case, fwiw.

Comment: Although it doesn't have to be escaped, not escaping the first asterisk will be more confusing from a casual observer, as if you're matching "any number of starts of lines followed by an asterisk".  Anything that makes a regexp more intuitive to a maintainer is a good idea. =)

Comment: Using double quotes would also prevent expansion, not only single quotes. Wrong advice here.

Comment: @rems4e using double quotes would prevent the shell from expanding the asterisks, but not from interpreting the backslashes. With double-quotes, you'd have to use `grep "^\\*\\*"` so that grep receives the `^\*\*` string that it needs to avoid interpreting the asterisks as regex quantifiers.

Answer (score 7):

As you wanted to check the line which starts with `**` and ends with `)`, you can combine two `grep` operation like this,

```
grep '^*\*' test.out | grep ')$'
```

Or with single `grep` command like this,

```
grep -E '^\*\*.*\)$' test.out
```

**Explanation**

- `^\*\*` : match line which starts with `**`
- `.*` : match everything after `**`
- `\)$` : match line which also has `)` at the end of line.

Answer (score 3):

#### It's not the shell

None of the answers so far has touched on the real problem. It would be helpful to explain *why* it does not work as you expect.

`grep -i "^**" test.out`

Because you have *quoted* the pattern to *grep*, `*` is *not* expanded by the shell. It is passed to *grep* as-is. This is explained in the manual page<sup>[1]</sup> for *bash*<sup>[2]</sup>:

> Enclosing  characters  in  double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \, and, when history expansion is enabled, !.

#### It's regular ordinary regular expressions

*A regular expression is a **pattern** that describes a set of strings.*

`*` is one of the key patterns in regular expressions. By default, *grep* interprets it as follows:

> `*   The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.`

This means that your pattern as it stands, `^**` does not make much sense. Possibly it tries to match the beginning of the line *zero or more times*, twice. Whatever that means.

The solution is to *quote* it:

> Any meta-character with special meaning may be quoted by preceding it with a backslash.

`grep -i "^\*\*" test.out`

---

<sup>[1] I do not recommend reading it. Please use `man dash` or similar instead.</sup>

<sup>[2] No shell was given, so I assume *bash*.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Other options.

You can use `sed` or `awk` also

```
$ sed -n '/^*\*/p' test.out
$ awk '/^*\*/' test.out
```

To know lines that end with `)` use also `grep` or `sed` or `awk`

```
$ grep ')$' test.out
$ sed -n '/)$/p' test.out
$ awk '/)$/' test.out
```

Comment: Thanks everyone !   I really appreciate the help on this one!

Comment: And the combined awk line: `'/^*\*/&&/)$/'`...

Answer (score 0):

This is the completely unquoted version: `grep ^\\*\\* test.out`. To pass a literal backslash from the shell to grep, it needs to be escaped.

This works as long as you have no files in the directory starting with `^\` and containing another backslash.